# java alternative Thread.stop() to interrupt specific call

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I am searching for a way to tell this call, which takes about 20-120 seconds:

```
final Area image = ...
final AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.scale...
image.transform(transform); //this specific line takes that long
```

to stop if Thread.interrupt() is called;

Because I just want to call that once, I cannot run some stuff in a while(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) loop and throw an InterruptedException. I can run if isNotInterrupted before and after the call, but still, how to stop this line of code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread interruption in Java is cooperative.

But I believe you understand that. If your affine transform takes that long to run and you try and run it in one go without even checking for the interrupted flag, your transform will happily transform along.

There is no `Thread.kill()`.

You have no choice. Note that I don't know whether it is possible but ideally such a long running thread should be spliced into manageable timeable chunks and the interrupt flag checked between these chunks.

Of course, you also have the option to *not* run that transform in the current thread but in an `ExecutorService` instead, and grab a `Future` of the result; and you would `.get()` with timeout.

But the end problem will remain: you MUST check for the interrupt flag. And you will have to deal with a `TimeoutException` on `.get()`.

---

OK, I suck at math. But can't this transform be split in several threads? Can't you use, for instance, the fork/join framework? Or better yet, if you use Java 8, a `Stream` and a `Collector`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know how to split the transform. I am rewriting my code using the ExecutorService as you said. It looks good for now