# Non-cooperative Thread.stop() alternative in modern Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

`Thread.stop()` is now removed from modern Android API. From https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#stop(),

> **Many uses** of `stop` should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, ...

I suppose that a complete removal of a method must be backed by an alternative of it, both for the **many uses** where it is replaceable, and for the many other uses where it is not. I am therefore wondering what is the alternative of `Thread.stop()` that stops a thread where cooperative interruption flags do not work, which is possibly due to e.g. calls of slow 3rd-party functions.

From the articles I've googled and the duplicated SO questions I've read about this issue, I got only two unsatisfactory types of answers:

1. You should just consider cooperative interruption because it's not stupid.
2. `Thread.stop()` is now gone for whatever reason so just forget it.

I would appreciate a lot if you could either provide a functioning alternative of `Thread.stop()` or explain the rationale behind removing it despite the legitimate use cases depending on it, where "legitimate" implies nonexistence of any synchronization and locking issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `stop()` has been deprecated for nearly 20 years, at least back to [Java 1.4.2](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/).

Comment: @CommonsWare indeed, but I woudn't ask if it were just deprecated instead of completely deleted

Comment: It was removed from Java by Oracle a couple of years ago. AFAIK, developers working with low-level thread stuff are using `interrupt()`. That's also one of Oracle's recommended alternatives. Perhaps you might ask your question in the [java] tag. You might also consider posting a [mcve] demonstrating something that you believe is impossible to solve with `interrupt()` and requires `stop()`. I can see some scenarios for this, mostly involving calling flawed C/C++ code via JNI.

Comment: But, in the end, advice is likely to be scenario-specific, rather than some universal `stop()` replacement. After all, if a universal `stop()` replacement were practical, one imagines that Sun or Oracle would have implemented it. So, a question in the [java] tag with a [mcve] of your specific concern is more likely to get you help.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the pointers, I've added the java tag. And you're right, the 3rd party library I'm using includes native code indeed, which is "flawed" in the sense that it exposes no interface for cooperative interruption. A similar question with examples has been asked at <https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555779/13950559>, which received only disappointing answers. I avoided giving such concrete examples because, comparing to practically helpful suggestions of specific "non-flawed" alternative libraries, I would prefer a coherent story around the flawed but common libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "modern" alternative.  The old alternatives are still the only ones.  Why?  Because this is fundamentally an *unsolvable* problem<sup>1</sup> ... if the threads are not cooperating / checking for thread interrupts, or if they unable to *correctly* deal with a thread interrupt.

For the record, the technical reasons that `Thread.stop()` is unsafe *include*:

- It breaks mutual exclusion locks help by the thread being stopped.  This may leave the object that was locked ... or other objects ... in an inconsistent state.
- It may result in broken inter-thread signalling.  For example, if a thread is expected to notify a condition variable, and it gets stopped before this happen, then other threads may be stuck forever waiting for a notify that never arrives.

If has said that, issues such as the above can *in theory* be addressed by application code on a case-by-base basis.  For example, if you were using `stop()` you could catching `ThreadDeath` in all of the necessary places, take remedial action and then rethrow it.  But to borrow someone else's words, "it would be insanely messy".

---

I'm sorry if you think this is all unsatisfactory.  But this is life.  If you cannot write your threads to be cooperative, and you *need* them to be killable, run them in an external process, via `Process` etcetera.

Now ... if we could wave a magic wand and replace Java threads with a CSP-like model of concurrency (and in doing so, eschew state sharing between processes), then the problem goes away.  Though now you have to deal with the other problem of what to do with the messages queued up when a process is terminated.  But at least that is a tractable problem.

---

<sup>1 - I am asserting this without proof!  However, if it was a solvable problem, then you would have thought that Sun or Oracle or Google or someone smart academic would have discovered and implemented a solution in the last ... umm ... 25 years.  **Challenge**: If you can come up with a viable implementation model for *safely* killing Java threads, I expect that certain companies would be willing to offer you a very well-paid job.  Especially if they can secure exclusive rights on your patent!!</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `Process` is indeed a last resort, but before that, I would rather make my own JNI using `pthread_kill`. Since it would behave very similarly with `Thread.stop()`, it baffles me even more that `stop` was removed in the first place.

Comment: Using `pthread_kill` would be *unsafer* than `Thread.stop`.  The reasons for the removal of `stop` are well documented.

Comment: The documentation explained quite well indeed that `Thread.stop` is not perfect, but I don't find it  justifying anything close to the removal of it. With a bit exaggeration, it says something like "since indexing an array with negative numbers would cause overflows, let's drop the signed integral types altogether and instead use pairs of unsigned in absolute urgent cases" which is insane.

Comment: Shrug ... you are entitled to your opinion.  However, this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: You're right, but since the question is rather general and I'm not experienced with java, it's still good to know that this is a legit opinion instead of some obvious newbie mistake.